# How do I inherit the TCPIP class correctly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, tcp

I wanted to create a TCPIP object inside a class. I have some problems to figure out how to done this.

First I will show a working code snippet:

```
>> %Creating the TCPIP object
>> TCPIP = tcpip('localhost',1000)

   TCPIP Object : TCPIP-localhost

   Communication Settings 
    RemotePort:         1000
    RemoteHost:         localhost
    Terminator:         'LF'
    NetworkRole:        client

   Communication State 
    Status:             closed
    RecordStatus:       off

   Read/Write State  
    TransferStatus:     idle
    BytesAvailable:     0
    ValuesReceived:     0
    ValuesSent:         0


>> %Changing Buffersize as example
>> TCPIP.OutputBufferSize = 30000

    TCPIP Object : TCPIP-localhost

    Communication Settings 
     RemotePort:         1000
     RemoteHost:         localhost
     Terminator:         'LF'
     NetworkRole:        client

    Communication State 
     Status:             closed
     RecordStatus:       off

    Read/Write State  
     TransferStatus:     idle
     BytesAvailable:     0
     ValuesReceived:     0
     ValuesSent:         0
```

As you can see the command line output of the Buffersize change is not shown. I can't visualize this correctly but I try to explain: After creating the TCPIP object Matlab creates the variable `TCPIP` with the value `1x1 tcpip`. If I double click this value I can see all properties of the object, including `outputBuffersize`.

Now I will show my first try of implemantation in class. I tryied to create the tcpip object inside a methode that saves the variable `TCPIP` (like explained before) inside my class properties.

```
classdef tcp_test < handle

    properties
        TCPIP
    end

    methods

         %CONSTRUCTOR
         function Obj = tcp_test(~)      
             ipobject(Obj);
         end

         %DECONSTRUCTER
         function delete(~) 
         end

         %Create TCPIP Object
         function ipobject(Obj)
             Obj.TCPIP = tcpip('localhost',1000);
             Obj.TCPIP.OutputBufferSize = 30000;
         end
    end
end
```

This class example is working with any error output, but I recognized something that seems not working as I expected. After creating the class object ´myTCP = tcp_test´ I tryed to investigate the the Object ´myTCP.TCPIP´ and realized that it looks like empty. Actually all necessary properties are set and I can change them, they are just not shown.

This leads to the original Question: I thought I have to inherit the tcpip class to use the class methods.

I still have the feeling that I still doing something wrong, because of the missing visualisatiuon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a lack of understanding what is displayed in the command window - it's not all of the properties of the object, sometimes just a subset. If you type `get( TCPIP )` in the command window, you will see all properties *including* the `OutputBufferSize`. Similarly, `t = tcp_test; get( t.TCPIP )` will show the same properties.

You can see, from typing `edit tcpip` in the command window, that the `tcpip` class has the following properties:

```
properties(Hidden, SetAccess = 'public', GetAccess = 'public')
    icinterface
end
```

It inherits from the `instrument` class which is not editable, and will have other properties we can't see the definitions for.

The important thing here is the `Hidden` attribute. From the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html):

> **MATLAB does not display in the command window the names and values of properties** having protected or private GetAccess or properties **whose Hidden attribute is true.**

This is why you can't *see* the property in the workspace. However, you can freely edit the properties, and view them using the general `get( TCPIP )`, or a specific `get` command:

```
outBuffer = get( TCPIP, 'OutputBuffer' );
```

More simply done with dot indexing

```
outBuffer = TCPIP.OutputBuffer;
```

Comment: Thx Wolfie you are right. It was a lack of understanding, that the ´Hidden´ is the importnat Option. It is a bit iritating that it has different behaviour when using it inside or outside a class.

Comment: @MaKa You mean `get( TCPIP )` vs `get( t.TCPIP )`? You're just accessing different things, if `tcp_test` was a subclass of `TCPIP` (as you originally put) then the behaviour would be the same - instead of `tcp_test` having a `tcpip` type property.